# Who are the major thinkers of Act, Rule, and Motive Utilitarianism?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, utilitarianism

If one sought to present utilitarianism through the work of three of its prominent 20th Century theorists, which ones would make the most sense in the context of a general overview of the literature on act utilitarianism, rule utilitarianism, and motive utilitarianism?

Answer (score 1):

Three well-known 20th/21st Century Utilitarians:

[Peter Singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Singer), currently at Princeton. Famous for the article "[Famine, Affluence, and Morality](http://www.utilitarian.net/singer/by/1972----.htm)"

[J.J. C. Smart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._C._Smart) co-author of [*Utilitarianism for and Against*](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=J0w3ER2fWv4C&redir_esc=y).

[R.M. Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._M._Hare) famous for defending a version of what is often considered rule utilitarianism. (Not to be confused with his son who is also a philosopher)

Comment: Quick question: For rule-utilitarianism, would you feature Hare over Harsanyi? Would Hare provide a better general overview of rule-utilitarianism for readers? Or, would it be better to feature Harsanyi and show that he followed from Hare's work?

Comment: I think I misread your question. I'm not a utilitarian so I may not be the person to pick the absolute best three representatives for the position. These are three that first sprang to mind in the contemporary context for me.